# Count the number of rows in Powershell Array

Tags: powershell

The I wrote the below script to return the name of all the Organisational Units in the domain that are empty.

I would like the script to also tell me the total number of empty OU's at the end, by counting the lines returned.  I've tried assigning an `$array` to the `New-Object`, and adding various versions of `$array.count` or `| Measure-Object` at the end of the script, but all return `0`.

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * |
foreach {
    $o = Get-ADObject -filter * -searchbase $_.distinguishedname -searchscope 1
    $total = ($o | Measure-Object).Count 
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name=$_.distinguishedname
        } |
        where-object {$total -le "0"}
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | 
Where-Object { -not (Get-ADObject -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel) }


# get the count
$ou|measure

$list OUs
$ou
```

Comment: As always, you do the job in half the code, and your answer is right on the money, so I'll be accepting this as the answer.  However, I didn't expect it to be **so** good.  See I wanted to keep some flexibility in the script, in case my colleagues wanted to look for OU's that only had a couple of objects in an OU.

Is there a way to keep the `-le "0"`, or similar in the script so the so the number of objects searched for can be changed?

Comment: Thanks, I geuss you can do: where{ @(Get-ADObject -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel).Count -le $number}